# Can't locate perl module

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to run a perl script on a machine using CentOS Linux 7. I have perl 5.36.1. The script uses a program called polymake which has its own copy of perl. I cannot modify that copy of perl. I can install modules for my copy of perl using cpan.

Using cpan, I have installed the module Algorithm::Combinatorics

```
$ cpanm Algorithm::Combinatorics
Algorithm::Combinatorics is up to date. (0.27)
```

In "~/perl5/lib/perl5/Algorithm," there is a file called "Combinatorics.pm."

When I run the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib '~/perl5/lib/perl5/Algorithm';
use lib '~/perl5/lib/perl5/';

use Combinatorics;
```

I get the error message

```
Can't locate Combinatorics.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Combinatorics module)
(@INC contains:  ~/perl5/lib/perl5/ ~/perl5/lib/perl5/Algorithm Polymake::Core::Application=ARRAY(0x3b5c670) /share/software/user/open/polymake/4.10/share/polymake/perllib [...])
```

When I do the same thing with the module List::Compare, I have no problem.

UPDATE:

Here is a more minimal example: I made a file called `perlscripttest.pl.`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics "subsets";



print(subsets[1,2,3,4]);
```

Then `perl perlscripttest.pl` gives the error:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Algorithm::Combinatorics in @INC 
(@INC contains: /share/software/user/open/polymake/4.10/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/share/software/user/open/polymake/4.10/share/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/users/mwlarson/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/users/mwlarson/perl5/lib/perl5 
/share/software/user/open/perl/5.36.1/lib/site_perl/5.36.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/share/software/user/open/perl/5.36.1/lib/site_perl/5.36.1 
/share/software/user/open/perl/5.36.1/lib/5.36.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /share/software/user/open/perl/5.36.1/lib/5.36.1) at perlscripttest.pl line 6.
```

Doing the same thing with List::Compare results in no error.

Comment: Are you suggesting adding "use lib '/perl5/lib/perl5/Algorithm';"? That did not fix the problem.

Comment: @MattLarson "_Are you suggesting..._"   -- that `~` in `use lib` still works but I'd suggest to generally not use `~`, which is really a shell thing and may or may not be understood by various pieces of Perl, but rather use `$ENV{HOME}` instead.

Comment: @MattLarson Now as for your problem ... why does your `@INC` have that `polymake` thing?  (The test program you show uses the system perl, given in the shebang line.) Is it added in `PERL5LIB`?  Then how does `PERL5LIB` look?  (Btw, is `List::Compare` in `polymake`?)

Comment: This script is being run as part of a larger polymake script, so I guess that is adding the polymake stuff. Polymake's copy of perl does not contain List::Compare.

Comment: PERL5LIB is ``/share/software/user/open/polymake/4.10/share/perl5/lib/perl5:/home/users/mwlarson/perl5/lib/perl5``

Comment: So I think I shouldn't even have to ``use lib foo``, if I have ``use Algorithm::Combinatorics,`` but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no directory named `~` in the CWD. The directive should be

```perl
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5";
```

However, it doesn't make much sense to specify where to look in the script since this is a directory usable by any script (i.e. absolute path). Instead, I'd set env var `PERL5LIB`.

```bash
export PERL5LIB="$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5"
```

---

The second error is due to an incomplete or incompatible version of the module installed in `/share/software/user/open/polymake/4.10/share/perl5/lib/perl5`. This should not be in PERL5LIB, or it should be after `$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5`.

Comment: I find tilde to work under `use lib` (in v5.32), like `perl -wE'use lib "~/perl5"; say for @INC; system("ls $INC[0]")'` prints the content of that directory.   (Go figure. Of course that that shoudln't be used) The second error is what gets them...